# Difference of sets with size of them

Tags: measure-theory

$X$ is an uncountable set and $\mathcal B$ is the sigma-algebra of all the subsets $A\subseteq X$ such that either $A$ is countable or $X\setminus A$ is countable. How to prove that $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ is a $\mathcal B$-measurable function if and only if there is an uncountable set $A_f\in\mathcal B$ such that $\left.f\right\rvert_{A_f}$ is constant?

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. What have you tried? Do you have any ideas on how you might attack this problem? We can help you better once we know exactly where you're stuck, and people will respond better if it doesn't look like you want us to do your homework for you

Answer (score 0):

First assume that there is an uncountable set $A_f\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $f|_{A_f}=k$ a constant. Then by definition $X\setminus A_f$ is countable. This means that $f$ can only take countably many values ($k$ and $f(x)$ for each of the countably many $x\in X\setminus A_f$). Thus any Borel set $B\subset[0,\infty]$ interects at most countably many of these values. If $k\notin B$ then $f^{-1}(B)\subset X\setminus A_f$ and thus must be countable and so $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{B}$. If $k\in B$ then consider $B\setminus\{k\}$, which is itself a Borel set. We have shown that $f^{-1}(B\setminus\{k\})\in\mathcal{B}$. Additionally $f^{-1}(\{k\})=A_f\cup\{\text{some (countable) subset of }X\setminus A_f\}\in\mathcal{B}$. Thus $f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}(B\setminus\{k\})\cup f^{-1}(\{k\})$ which is clearly in $\mathcal{B}$. Therefore $f$ is $\mathcal{B}$-measurable.

Now to show the other implication assume that $f$ is $\mathcal{B}$-measurable. Then for any Borel set $B\subset[0,\infty]$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is countable or $X\setminus f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}([0,\infty]\setminus B)$ is countable. Notice $[0,\infty]=\cup_{k=1}^\infty[\frac{k-1}{m},\frac{k}{m}]$ for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Fix $m$. If $f^{-1}([\frac{k-1}{m},\frac{k}{m}])$ is countable for all $k$ then $f^{-1}([0,\infty])=X$ would be countable since the countable union of countable sets is countable. Thus there exists $k$ such that $f^{-1}([\frac{k-1}{m},\frac{k}{m}])$ is not countable, and thus $X\setminus f^{-1}([\frac{k-1}{m},\frac{k}{m}])=f^{-1}([0,\infty]\setminus[\frac{k-1}{m},\frac{k}{m}])$ is countable. Notice that this means that there can be only one such $k$ for each $m$ since $[0,\infty]\setminus[\frac{k-1}{m},\frac{k}{m}]=\cup_{l=1,l\neq k}^\infty[\frac{l-1}{m},\frac{l}{m}]$. Thus we get a sequence $\{k_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ such that $f^{-1}([\frac{k_m-1}{m},\frac{k_m}{m}])$ is uncountable. Notice also that these intervals must be nested. A decreasing nested sequence of closed compact sets has non-empty intersection and because the length of these intervals goes to zero $\cap_{m=1}^\infty[\frac{k_m-1}{m},\frac{k_m}{m}]=\{h\}\subset\mathbb{R}$. Thus
$$f^{-1}(\{h\})=f^{-1}(\cap_{m=1}^\infty [\frac{k_m-1}{m},\frac{k_m}{m}])=\cap_{m=1}^\infty f^{-1}([\frac{k_m-1}{m},\frac{k_m}{m}])$$
$$=\cap_{m=1}^\infty X\setminus(X\setminus f^{-1}([\frac{k_m-1}{m},\frac{k_m}{m}]))=X\setminus(\cup_{m=1}^\infty (X\setminus f^{-1}([\frac{k_m-1}{m},\frac{k_m}{m}])))$$
$X\setminus f^{-1}([\frac{k_m-1}{m},\frac{k_m}{m}])$ is countable and the countable union of countable sets is countable so $\cup_{m=1}^\infty (X\setminus f^{-1}([\frac{k_m-1}{m},\frac{k_m}{m}]))$ is countable. Thus since $X$ is uncountable, $X\setminus(\cup_{m=1}^\infty (X\setminus f^{-1}([\frac{k_m-1}{m},\frac{k_m}{m}])))$ is uncountable and in $\mathcal{B}$ by definition of $\mathcal{B}$. Therefore $f^{-1}(\{h\})$ is uncountable and in $\mathcal{B}$.